# My comments doesn't appear on my comment section unless i add them via console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, comments

So I got into trouble with ruby on rails while creating comments. I don't get any errors, but my comments doesn't show up either.What am i doing wrong ? I am trying to debug it for past 2 hours :X

my show.html.erb

```html
<h2>Comments</h2>

   <%=  @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <strong><%= comment.body %></strong> <br />
      <hr />
<% end %>

<%= form_tag :action => "comment", :id => @article %>
   <%= text_area "comment", "body" %><br />
   <%= submit_tag "Comment" %>
</form>
```

my articles controller:

```
 def comment
   Article.find(params[:id]).comments.create(params[comment_params])
   flash[:notice] = "Added your comment"
   redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]
end
```

and my routes

```
 resources :articles do
  post 'comment', on: :member
end
```

Please tell me, why it doesn't save my text ? When i create a comment, i check it, and see:

```
#<Comment id: 21, email: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2014-04-27 13:27:40", updated_at: "2014-04-27 13:27:40", user_id: nil, article_id: 3>]
```

Don't mind the user_id: nil, i created it accidentally, and intend to remove it ^^ Once we fix this problem ^^

Comment: what do your `params` look like?

Comment: @JustinWood  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

Comment: If you change `params[comment_params]` to `params.require(:comment).permit(:body)` Does it work?

Comment: @JustinWood THANK YOU! I feel so stupid, that i didn't tried this, for so long i was mainly looking into my views, thinking that there was a problem :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you are attempting to use strong parameters.

You are currently doing

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
end

params[comment_params]
```

What you want to do is something like

```
def comment_params
  require(:comment).permit(:body)
end

params.comment_params
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
Article.find(params[:id]).comments.create(params[comment_params])
```

It should be like this

```
Article.find(params[:id]).comments.create(comment_params)
```